# Getting Data from session vs from parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, parameters

I have a method, and a `DataTable`. I have to use `DataTable` inside a method. I have already stored `DataTable` in `Session` for some use. I have two options to use `DataTable` in `C#` method

1. Pass as a parameter.
2. Get from `Session`.

Which one will harm performance less?

Comment: What makes you think that the performance will be hit at all?

Comment: POST data(pass as a parameter) has to travel back and forth through the net whereas session variables never leave the server.

Comment: But if you store that datatable in session, you don't have to pass as a parameter, because it's already in session. Use it directly. I suggest, cache that datatable if it's going to be stable for a while. And if session is specified per user, than your application performance is going to decrease.

Comment: Getting the DataTable from the session into the method will limit the usage of the method to only this datatable. If that's okay, it's better to get it from the session

Comment: Its pretty unclear what the actual `method` is - is it a simple method in a class at the server, or is it a client calling a controller-action or something similar...?

Comment: @Maarten Simple server side matter- I m sorry if it does matter

Comment: @SMI I thought so. See my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(after you indicated that this all refers to a server side method calling)

IMHO it doesn't matter at first glance. If you pass the table directly, or you retrieve your table from the (in-memory) session, all you do is pass/retrieve the reference to your datatable. No performance difference measurable I think.

But one thing to remember is that the session is not meant for this. If you store more objects in the session, for different purposes, for different users, then eventually your session will taker a larger chunk of memory. Eventually this will hurt performance.

KIS (Keep It Simple) - use parameters. Easy, clear, and the best performance.

Comment: I have already stored table in session for another purpose, but, as you said 'No performance difference measurable', I am getting it from session itself. :)